# How to set button backgroundimage in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm new in this field. I'm working in windows application, I create panel and adding the buttons inside the panel. i want to retrieve the image from database and set to the background image in button.

This is my code,

```
FileName = objDR["Photopath"].ToString();
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FileName);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
Buttons[i].BackgroundImage = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

initially put BackgroundImage  property ON

OR

You can Code :

```
button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Image));
```

Comment: i try to this but i get this error "Parameter is not Valid."

Comment: @SruthiP just debug the code why it is not working https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/415009/parameter-is-not-valid